Safari text recognition in images (live text)
I'm building a new portfolio and when I open it in Safari, it add some artifacts on images when hovering. It's because of the Safari "Live Text" default setting that recognise text and numbers inside pixelated images. So, I would like to know if there is a way to disable Safari Live Text through css or javascript? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Did you try this
